Convex optimization and coercive function(Gausssian graphical lasso)
I want to minimize the following function (with $<A,B> = tr(A^T B)$)
$<\Theta, \hat \Sigma> - \log det \Theta + \lambda_n \lVert \Theta \rVert_{1, off}$
over the set of symmetric positive definite matrices, where $ \lVert \Theta \rVert_{1, off} = \sum_{i \neq j} \left| \Theta_{ij} \right|$.
It's easy to find that the global minimum would be achieved at the matrix $\hat \Theta$ that satisfies
$\hat \Sigma - \hat \Theta^{-1} + \lambda_n \hat Z = 0$, where $\hat Z$ is in the subgradient of $\partial \lVert \hat \Theta \rVert_{1, off}$.
However, I'm not sure how to guarantee that such a $\hat \Theta$ exists. It seems it has something to do with coercive functions, but this seems to only apply to closed and compact set.
Thank you.
Sidenote:
The question is from reading a paper. Here's the relevant section(note I want the proof in terms of unconstrained optimization)



Ravikumar, Pradeep; Wainwright, Martin J.; Raskutti, Garvesh; Yu, Bin, High-dimensional covariance estimation by minimizing (\ell _{1})-penalized log-determinant divergence, Electron. J. Stat. 5, 935-980 (2011). ZBL1274.62190.

Your sentence "This has something to do with coercive functions, but this seems to only apply to closed and compact set." makes no sense to me. The whole idea of coerciveness is to deal with noncompact domains.
First recall that every continuous function over a compact domain attains its extrema. Now, let $\mathcal{X}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be some closed unbounded set, and suppose we are studying a program of the form $\min_{\mathcal{X}} f(x)$. We say that $f$ is coercive if as $\|x\| \to \infty$ over the domain, it holds that $f(x) \to \infty$.
The standard result is this: suppose $f$ is coercive, and $\exists x_0 \in \mathcal{X}$ such that $f(x_0) < \infty$. Then a minimiser of $f$ exists. Indeed, since $f \to \infty$ as $\|x\| \to \infty,$ there exists some $r$ such that $\|x\| > r \implies f(x) > f(x_0)$. But $\min_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \le f(x_0),$ and thus $\min_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) = \min_{\mathcal{X} \cap \{\|x\| \le r\} } f(x),$ and now we're minimising over the closed and bounded (and thus compact) set $\mathcal{X} \cap \{\|x\| \le r\},$ so a minimiser must exist.
Now, in the case of the paper, they're first saying that the regularised problem can equivalently be seen as a constrained problem, where the $\ell_1$ norm of the off-diagonal entries of $\Theta$ is controlled. This makes the domain to be the set of $\Theta$s with nonnegative diagonal entries, and off-diagonal entries bounded in $\ell_1$. This is an unbounded domain, but the only unbounded parts are the diagonals of the $\Theta$s. Next, they observe that the objective is lower bounded by $\sum \Theta_{ii}\hat\Sigma_{ii} - \log\Theta_{ii},$ and observe that if $\hat\Sigma_{ii} > 0$ for all $i$, then if any $\Theta_{ii} \to \infty,$ this lower bound explodes to $\infty$. But the only way $\|\Theta\| \to \infty$ over the domain is if $\Theta_{ii} \to \infty$ for some $i$, and hence this shows that as $\|\Theta \|\to \infty$ over the domain, the objective explodes to $\infty$ too, ergo, the objective is coercive. This in turn means that as long as the objective is finite somewhere (you need to check this, but its kind of trivial here), the minimum is attained by some $\Theta$.
Strictly speaking the argument is not quite complete: for instance, it could be the case that there is some $\Theta$ which is only positive semidefinite that infimises the objective. This is, of course, also not the case, because this would cause the $-\log\det\Theta$ term to explode, but the $\langle \Theta, \hat\Sigma\rangle$ term would remain finite once one imposes a bound on $\max\Theta_{ii}$ (which we are free to do, since the objective diverges if these are large). In fact, in order to handle such cases, people sometimes state a stronger definition of coerciveness, that demands that $f \to \infty$ as $x \to \partial\mathcal{X}$ or as $\|x\|\to \infty.$  The objective from the paper is also coercive in this stronger sense.

So equivalently, I could check that if for some norm on the positive definite matrices, as the norm goes to infinity, the objective also goes to infinity, I'd prove that there must be a minimum somewhere.

Yup. More or less, all this boils down to is the following thought: my domain has some boundary, and some part scooting off to $\infty$. If the optimum lies there, I might be in trouble. So, how do I ensure that this doesn't happen? The clearest way is to say that there is some evidence that the optimal value is small, but in these bad parts of the domain, the objective takes a larger value, and that's enough to establish everything one needs. This can be concretised in many ways, including your suggestion above.

Since I can take any norm, I can just take the norm to be the maximum of the diagonal entries and apply the argument in the paper?

Sure. That's basically what the proof you've attached in the question analyses.
